# Using Boost C++ unit tests with visual studio and can't find .cpp files in other project

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I have a solution where I've added and setup boost unit tests. The problem is that I have another project I'd like to test that has some classes in it. In fact, that project is the main reason I added boost.

My project that needs testing is set to output as a .dll. And the problem is that, whenever my tests project needs to access code from the other projects, it can access the header just fine. However, if the header has unresolved code in it that's otherwise resolved in a .cpp file of the project with the objects, I receive a linking error. Is there a way around this? I'd ideally like to keep my objects in my other dll and then test them in my tests project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the visual studio compiler couldn't link to the CPP in the other files. I had to add the CPP files to the boost project as well using the existing files option.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not telling your test project where to find the symbols. Either link against your production code's .lib manually, or you can add the project as a reference and VS will link your projects automatically.

Go to your project's properties, under Common Properties choose Framework and References. Click the Add New References... button, and select your other project. Since it's a .dll, you then want to set Link Library Dependencies to False (save and reopen the dialog, that setting seems to be buggy).

Comment: Well, I just tried to add the project reference and set the link library dependencies to false. But it still can't find the code and resolves in a linking error.